# Gitkraken disable auto file renaming

Tags: git, macos, gitkraken

i noticed, that gitkraken renames automatically files, which filenames contains any special character. So äpfel.js becomes ?pfel.js or something else.

The problem is, that these files are provided by someone else, so the filenames should stay the same.

So is there any chance to change this behavior?
Sourcetree for example does not alter the filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gitkraken is new code and is still actively being developed. Let them know about the problem, they may not respond individually to your issue but keep an eye on the release notes to see when it is fixed.